# Nebular: Input with required asterick

Tags: nebular, required-field

I would like to add the standard asterisk on input fields that are required in a form.

Is there a directive or something to do that or do I have to create my own directive?

Is it possible to link this attribute to the validator?

Thank you for your help

Comment: There is no such directive in Nebular input, you'll have to create your own. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by `link this attribute to the validator`? Do you want some validation feedback, for example, the input to get a red border if not filled?